# adding columns to tableview in ipad

Tags: ipad

Is it possible to add columns to a table view in ipad?

If yes, please tell me how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put anything you like in a cell. But cells are essentially rows, so no, there's no built-in support for table columns.